# User Monitoring in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

We have an app with an extensive admin section. We got a little trigger happy with features (as you do) and are looking for some quick and easy way to monitor "who uses what".

Ideally a simple gem that will allow us to track controller/actions on a per user basis to build up a picture of the features that are used and those that are not.

Anything out there that you'd recommend..

Thanks

Dom

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know that there's a popular gem or plugin for this; in the past, I've implemented this sort of auditing as a `before_filter` in ApplicationController:

from memory:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :audit_events
  # ...

  protected
  def audit_events
    local_params = params.clone
    controller = local_params.delete(:controller)
    action = local_params.delete(:action)
    Audit.create(
      :user => current_user, 
      :controller => controller, 
      :action => action, 
      :params => local_params
    )
  end
end
```

This assumes that you're using something like restful_authentication to get current user, of course.

EDIT: Depending on how your associations are set up, you'd do even better to replace the Audit.create bit with this:

```
current_user.audits.create({
  :controller => controller,
  :action => action,
  :params => local_params
})
```

Scoping creations via ActiveRecord assoiations == best practice

Comment: You need to clone params or you risk breaking stuff with the delete!

Comment: I know it's two years since but with parameter filtering this one is better than `params`

`local_params request.filtered_parameters.dup`

Comment: why to use before_filter instead of after_filter?